# Cannot open websites, some of

Tags: networking, internet, 16.04, dns

Some websites cannot be shown on Ubuntu 16.04, how to fix it? Tried to clean dns as `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean start`.

Still nothing, some websites are, however, working - but some not.

Comment: What is "WMS" ?

Comment: Windows Microsoft, you are welcome. However the issue wasn't about it

Answer (score 1):

Solved, simple - check first browser's settings, after use hideip-vpn add-ons it set automatically proxy as system sets. Put on "off" and it will work normal. settings-advanced-network-setting-proxy-non

Comment: Since this helped, accept this answer by clicking the 'check mark' under the down arrow!

Comment: In 2 days it says me, ok

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to another DNS server, like Google Public DNS: `8.8.8.8` in Network settings.

Comment: Not solved it, on handy it works wonderful.

Comment: @OlegNagornov So - solved or not? Also, can you tell us what websites are unable to be accessed?

Comment: Of course not solved, i will inform all of you when itll work ok. It doesn't matter, just this page is working. If you do not know how to restart dns or any different ways for it don't answer ok.